# ViewModel does weired operation with OnViewCreated

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

See:

```
 var isShimmerCalled: Boolean = false

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        _binding = FragmentProductBinding.bind(view)
        setupRecyclerView()
        if (!isShimmerCalled) {
            Log.d("Main", "Called shimmer")
            startShimmerLayout()
            isShimmerCalled = true
        }
        setUpView()
        getProductData()
    }
```

So, I'm working with viewmodel and livedata, and as you see above, if `isShimmerCalled == false` then I'm printing log "Called Shimmer" and then my shimmer layout is displaying in UI. Fine.

```
D: setupRecyclerView
D: Called shimmer
```

Now I switch to next fragment (I've single activity with multiple fragment using navigation component) and then pressed back button

```
D: setupRecyclerView
```

So, notice here, only `setupRecyclerView` is printed because of that flag. that's correct.

**Then my question is why Shimmer layout is displayed in UI?**

**Edit:**
Complete code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rnx1etUjGsqlvt1Bxy-SPxTvvUDufash/view?usp=sharing

Should I do like this (**it's not my code, someone else project fragment, because in that person code this problem not happening**):

```
viewModel.breakingNews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
            when(response) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    response.data?.let { newsResponse ->
                        newsAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles)
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    response.message?.let { message ->
                        Log.e(TAG, "An error occured: $message")
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    showProgressBar()
                }
            }
        })
```

**EDIT:**Oh my gosh!! Even though I commented startShimmerLayout() still shimmer is showing

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.products.ProductFragment">

    <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shimmer_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Adding 3 rows of placeholders -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_layout" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_error"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_retry"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Results could not be loaded"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_retry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Retry"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have never used `ShimmerLayout` but you have to Stop animation too i guess When you done adding items to RV . Are u doing it ?

Comment: My uninformed guess, your Fragment View is cached by Android and so it's restored. Instead of `!isShimmercalled` in the fragment, this belongs on the ViewModel, which can talk to a Repository/UseCase/Interactor/YouNameIt that will know/store whether the "shimmer is called" and push the appropriate "state" to the Fragment (Which will be obviously observing said state from the VModel). The Fragment doesn't make a check/decision, the fragment observes said decision (and what to do) from its ViewModel.

Comment: @ADM I'm stopping it getProductData() that's not an issue.

Comment: It's perfectly normal for fragment to call `onViewCreated` multiple times, just be sure you clean up any state related to views inside `onDestroyView`.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Correct, I confirmed already then when I came back again, same view model object I'm getting, but how can I solved my problem? I don't want to call shimmer layout/api again once I came from another fragment by pressing back button

Comment: @Pawel Like viewmodel should I clear? then also it'll do the same right?

Comment: Your shimmer will start as soon as it gets attached to view.  You can either make shimmer view in gone state and based on logic, you can run shimmer & set visibility. Or make auto start shimmer false.
shimmerFrameLayout.setShimmer(Shimmer.AlphaHighlightBuilder().setAutoStart(false).build())

Comment: @KishanMaurya shimmer is just an examle. Along with shimmer getProductData is also called and API's are also calling, and recyclerview as well. I don't want that all again!

Comment: @Martin Marconcini, _"your Fragment View is cached by Android"_ - this is the 1st time I meet such a statement. Could you clarify or give a reference to that?

Comment: @SychiSingh You can trigger API call in onCreate of the fragment. Start observing live data from onViewCreated method. This will make sure only 1 API call.

Comment: @KishanMaurya I'm observing through viewmodel and inside setting reyclcerview, will it work, see the updated question

Answer (score 1):

**onCreateView()** is the Fragment equivalent of **onCreate()** for Activities and runs during the View creation.
**onViewCreated()** runs after the View has been created.

should I use one over the other for performance? **NO.** There's no evidence of a performance boost.

There is actually an **onCreate()** method in Fragments too, but it's rarely used (I do never use it, nor find a good use case for it).

I always use **onCreateView()** in Fragments
try placing this code in **onCreateView** instead

Comment: Fragments view lifecycle is **not** equal to fragments lifecycle itself. Fragments might undergo detachment which will destroy their view (fragment enters `STOPPED` state) and recreate the view when they're reattached without being completely destroyed.

Comment: what are you trying to explain as there are just 5 enum state of lifecycle and stopped is not one of them . Please be clear in your thought https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle

Comment: @Akash, I know all of this, where is the solution dear?

Comment: @Pawel solution I want, not lifecycle theory, please!

Comment: solution is to place it in onCreateView as everytime the fragment comes in foreground it gets called and recyclerview get its attribute set what haapens in this caseis that the view is created with default attribute and once the view is created you are setting or unsetting the shimmer view

Comment: I mean it calls stop so it goes back to `CREATED` state. But `viewLifecycle` itself is a separate entity and it's destroyed when fragment becomes detached, that's why there are weird abominations like `viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData` extensions in androidx library. Google is looking into simplifying this and aligning view lifecycle with fragment lifecycle itself but it's not done yet.

Comment: @AkashPal himmer is just an examle. Along with shimmer getProductData is also called and API's are also calling, and recyclerview as well. I don't want that all again!

Comment: yup @Pawel never denied it android ecosystem is in a messy state for sure

Comment: @SychiSingh so whats the issue cant we do those api calls in onCreateview instead

Comment: Sometime we get NPE or no data on view. Also it is recommeande that we should do inside onViewCreated not onCreateView

Comment: sorry for the late reply but according to your updated question you are using facebook shimmer layout and in that the implemntation is such that if thre are no item then the placeholder will be simmering by default

Comment: and yeah in java we get npe and they are frequent and you should handel thoes cases too. but in kotlin it auto handled so ....